# Error when using tikz \node, \subnode

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

In the code below, building off solutions found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291843/highlight-matrix-cell-and-have-arrows-pointing-from-cell-with-text), I am trying to use the `\node` and `\subnode` options to draw the arrow, but I cannot get the file to compile.  Can you help me to fix the code to get the arrow to point to the text and the highlighted cell like this[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\tikzset{%
  highlight/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=red!15,draw,
    fill opacity=0.5,thick,inner sep=0pt}
}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,
  baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {#2};}
%
\newcommand{\Highlight}[1][submatrix]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \node[highlight,fit=(left.north west) (right.south east)] (#1) {};}
}
\begin{document}
\[
  M = \left(\begin{array}{*5{c}}
    \tikzmark{left}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
    11 & 12 & \tikzmark{right}{13} & 14 & 15 \\
    16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20
  \end{array}\right)
  \Highlight[first]
  \qquad
  M^T = \left(\begin{array}{*5{c}}
    \tikzmark{left}{1} & 6 & 11 & 16 \\
    2 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\
    3 & 8 & \tikzmark{right}{13} & 18 \\
    4 & 9 & 14 & 19 \\
    5 & 10 & 15 & 20
  \end{array}\right)
\]
\Highlight[second]
%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[->,thick,red,dashed] (first) -- (second) node [pos=0.66,above] {Transpose};
  \node[above of=first] {$N$};
  \node[above of=second] {$N^T$};
}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} & x_{4} &  \\
\begin{block}{[cccc|c]}
  1 & 0 & \tikzmark{left}{-1} & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \tikz{\node{\subnode{d1}\tikzmark{right}{0}};} & 1 & 0 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\Highlight[new1]
\]

%\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%    \node [shift={(3.0em,-4.0ex)}, anchor=west] at ({pic cs:starta}) (X) {Tip measurement};
%    \draw [mybluei, thick, -latex] (X.west) -| ($({pic cs:starta})!0.5!({pic cs:enda})+(0,-0.5ex)$);
%\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The basic problem is that `\subnode` is not defined. You don't define it and you don't load anything which defines it. To use it, you need to load the `tikzmark` library. However, it defines `\tikzmark` so you can't use this and then say `\newcommand\tikzmark...`. If you need your definition of the marks, you can simply use a different name. `\newcommand\mytikzmark...` will work fine. However, I cannot figure out what you want to do with the `\subnode` command. This should take 2 arguments: name of the subnode and contents of the subnode. You just have one.

Comment: Also, you try to also use `\mytikzmark` within the node, but that is not going to work. That is why `\subnode` was written: so that you could mark stuff within nodes, when the usual methods of setting `tikzmark`s (however defined) aren't available. So either don't use a subnode here or a TikZ picture and just use `\mytikzmark`. Or use `\subnode`s inside the TikZ picture. But I can't see why you want a TikZ picture here. What are you trying to produce exactly?

Comment: @cfr, thanks for your comments.  Please see my updated question with the image of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the problem with the code is that `\subnode` is never defined. You can get it defined by loading the `tikzmark` library. However, `\newcommand\tikzmark...` will then fail as the library defines the standard `\tikzmark` command. This problem can be avoided by simply choosing a different macro name, such as `\mytikzmark`.

You cannot, however, use `\mytikzmark` or `\tikzmark` inside a node inside a TikZ picture. Indeed, the raison d'être of `\subnode` is for use in this context precisely because `tikzmark`s cannot be used there.

So you can either use `\mytikzmark` or `\tikzmark` without the surrounding TikZ picture environment. Or you can use `\subnode`s within one.

Here's a comparison of the two methods:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}
\tikzset{%
  highlight/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=red!15,draw, fill opacity=0.5,thick,inner sep=0pt}
}
\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {#2};}

\newcommand{\Highlight}[1][submatrix]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \node[highlight,fit=(left.north west) (right.south east)] (#1) {};}
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
    x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} & x_{4} &  \\
    \begin{block}{[cccc|c]}
      1 & 0 & \mytikzmark{left}{-1} & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & \tikz{\node{\subnode{d1}{d1}\subnode{right}{0}};} & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
  \Highlight[new1]
\]
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
  \node [fit=(d1), inner sep=-2.5pt, draw=blue, circle] {};
  \node [fit=(right), inner sep=-2.5pt, draw=green!50!black, circle] {};
}
\[
  \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
    x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} & x_{4} &  \\
    \begin{block}{[cccc|c]}
      1 & 0 & \mytikzmark{left}{-1} & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & \mytikzmark{d1}{d1} \mytikzmark{right}{0} & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
  \Highlight[new1]
\]
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
  \node [fit=(d1), inner sep=-2.5pt, draw=blue, circle] {};
  \node [fit=(right), inner sep=-2.5pt, draw=green!50!black, circle] {};
}

\end{document}
```

[image: subnodes and tikzmarks]

Given your updated question, I don't think you want `\subnode` at all. Why not just use the marks you already have?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
  highlight/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=red!15,draw, fill opacity=0.5,thick,inner sep=0pt}
}
\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {#2};}

\newcommand{\Highlight}[1][submatrix]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \node[highlight,fit=(left.north west) (right.south east)] (#1) {};}
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
    x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} & x_{4} &  \\
    \begin{block}{[cccc|c]}
      1 & 0 & \mytikzmark{left}{-1} & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & \mytikzmark{right}{0} & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
  \Highlight[new1]
\]
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
  \draw [LaTeX-] (new1.south) ++(0,-2.5pt) [out=-90,in=160] to ++(5mm,-10mm) node [right, xshift=-2.5mm, font=\itshape, text=red, align=center] {free\\variable};
}

\end{document}
```

[image: use existing marks to add annotation]

Comment: I think you should add `TikZnician` to you title :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you can do with the environment `{bNiceArray}` of `nicematrix` (with the lastest version: v. 5.12 of 2021-03-10).

That environment is similar to `{array}` (of `array`) but constructs PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns).

I have used these nodes to draw the arrow and its label. For the highlighted column, there is a built-in command `\Block` easy to use (you don't need transparency).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{cccc|c}[first-row]
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\
1   & 0   & \Block[draw,fill=red!10,rounded-corners]{3-1}{}-1  & 0  & 0 \\
0   & 1   & 2   & 0  & 0 \\
0   & 0   & 0   & 1  & 0 
\CodeAfter
\tikz
\draw [<-] (3-3.south) ++(0,-5pt) [out=-90,in=160] to ++(5mm,-10mm) 
    node [right, xshift=-2.5mm, font=\itshape, text=red, align=center] {free\\variable} ;
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/tikz nodes).

[image: output of the above code]